# Euclidian Distance math error

Tags: python, math, euclidean-distance

```
import math
from math import sqrt

Hailey=[0,4,1,4,0,0,4,1]
Verica=[3,0,0,5,4,2.5,3,0]
temp=[]
distance=0
x=0

for i in range(0,len(Hailey)):
    if (Hailey[i]!=0 and Verica[i]!=0):
        temp[x]=math.sqrt(abs(Hailey[i]**2) - abs(Verica[i]**2))
        x=x+1
for i in range(0,len(temp)):
    distance=distance+temp[i]
print("distance is",distance)
```

Im trying to make a program that finds the euclidian distance between 2 people. It doesnt seem mathematically corret and im getting this:

```
    distance=distance + math.sqrt(abs(Hailey[i]**2) - abs(Verica[i]**2))
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: Hailey=[0,4,1,4,0,0,4,1] ** i accidentaly wipped 1 digit while copy/pasting

Comment: Your next error will come from the fact that you cannot append to a list by assigning to an non-existent index. Get rid of `x` and use `temp.append(math.sqrt(...))`.

Comment: Sidenote: `for i in range(0,len(temp)):` is usually not the most Pythonic approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula you are using isn't quite right. Here is the [correct formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#N_dimensions):

```
>>> math.sqrt(sum((h-v)**2 for h, v in zip(Hailey, Verica)))
7.158910531638177
```

Or, if you feel like using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
>>> Hailey = numpy.array([0,4,1,4,0,0,4,1])
>>> Verica = numpy.array([3,0,0,5,4,2.5,3,0])
>>> numpy.linalg.norm(Hailey - Verica)
7.1589105316381767
```

Comment: i guess this is way better than mine altough i still get an error :

temp[x]=math.sqrt(sum(h-v)**2 for h,v in zip(Hailey,Verica))
TypeError: a float is required